# Tensorflow-gpu with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pyinstaller

Trying to distribute a program that relies on tensorflow...

Using tensorflow it works nicely both as script and with pyinstaller.
Using tensorflow-gpu it works as script but not with pyinstaller.
The cuda and cudnn dlls have been copied into the bundle folder by pyinstaller.

I use python 3.6.5 and tensorflow 1.7.0. (Can change version if it helps...)

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>     File "c:\users\aleks\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
>     File "importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "interface.py", line 14, in 
>     File "c:\users\aleks\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>     File "c:\users\aleks\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>     File "c:\users\aleks\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>     File "c:\users\aleks\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
>     File "importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.
>   [10816] Failed to execute script interface

Comment: Sometimes errors like that come up when the current directory has a `tensorflow` subdirectory with an `__init__.py` in it, which Python will prefer to any other installations. (Or something similar; a `tensorflow.py` might work too.)

Comment: I have same issue. Did you end up solving it Aleksk89?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are also packaging `MSVCP140.DLL`, as missing this from the %PATH% can throw this error.

I tend to use cx_Freeze instead of pyinstaller when distributing tensorflow applications. Once you overcome the error cx_Freeze has with scipy, it's simpler overall.

Comment: Good tip :) Too long since I have worked on this project. So doubt I will get to test it out, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732801/windows-10-pyinstaller-tensorflow-missing-modules/50580345) can help. I manually rename the file `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` to `tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` in the dist folder. Everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by making dirs as ".../dist/[MmyPyName]/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd"

- tensorflow-gpu = 1.10.0
- python = 3.6.2
- cuda = 9.0
- cudnn = 7.3.0

Answer (score 0):

When installing it with pyinstaller, make sure that in the .spec file include this as hidden import:

```
hiddenimports=['tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal',],
```

This will include the missing module in the correct path.