# Windows 10 pyinstaller tensorflow missing modules

Tags: tensorflow, pyinstaller

I try to deploy a model with pyinstaller and when i run it i get the following error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Tensorflow 1.7.0

cudnn64_7

CUDA 9.0

Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue by simply renaming the file `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` contained in the dist folder to `tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd`.
I still have to figure out how to tell pyinstaller the "correct" module name.

Answer (score 0):

( Workaround for Python 3.5 only )

Building off of Jascha's solution, a work around is to manually fetch the file  **__python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd** from

*PathToAnaconda3/env//Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd*

and rename it into **tensorflow.python.__python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd**

Then this renamed file can be moved into the exe file by :

```
pyinstaller -F <name of python file> --add-data "pathToFile/tensorflow.python.__python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd";.
```

The flag --add-data takes two arguments separated by semi colon

```
--add-data source_path;destination_path_inside_exe
```

Comment: I tried the way you said with no luck. I am using pyinstaller to pack my py file into one .exe on windows. Are we using the same system?

Comment: I am using python 3.5, on Windows 10 64 bit. I am sorry, I forgot to mention, it doesn't work for python 3.6.

Comment: I am using python 3.5.1, but I could not find the 
tensorflow folder and __python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd file in the Anaconda directory. I have installed tensorflow version 1.10.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl. How did you installed your tensorflow?

Comment: @EdwinYeo Actually it's not the file inside your Anaconda directory, but the file inside your distribution folder, the folder with your generated *.exe. If you just have a single .exe because you are using pyinstaller's --one-file flag, remove this flag. Then, simply move _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd from root to ./tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd and launch your program.exe. It should work

Comment: I installed tensorflow using pip

What Overdrivr said will also work but you wont have a single .exe file. Basically when you want to generate single exe file, you must manually tell pyinstaller to copy the required .pyd file into the exe file.

(a) You can just search where ever your tensorflow is installed for the __python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd and follow the steps in the OP

OR

(b) You can do what EdwinYeo said, and get the pyd file from the generated dist folder and rebuild a exe file using that.

Comment: I should have clarified my answer, indeed if you want a single exe, you should find a way to tell pyinstaller to move the _pywrap_... file to `tensorflow/python` (or rename it to tensorflow.python._pywrap... prior to running pyinstaller, but I have not tried this one). My comment was merely to help you understand why the import fails.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` as a binary file when compiling using pyinstaller

I am using Tensorflow 2.10, Python 3.10 and Pyinstaller 5.13.0. Here is what I have done:

In the `.spec` file,

```
a = Analysis(
  ['test.py'],

  pathex=[],

  binaries=[('path_to_tensorflow_python_folder\_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd', '.')],

  ...
)
```