# Packaging Issue with Pyinstaller and Tensorflow on Python 3.6 (_pywrap_tensorflow_internal)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I have used Pyinstaller (3.4) other times with python 3.6 on windows 10, but this time I am having trouble with the module _pywrap_tensorflow_internal (tensorflow-gpu 1.12). 
The program runs perfectly on the computer where it is generated, but on other computers (with the same OS version) there is a path problem.

I have found some threads ([Tensorflow-gpu with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620638/tensorflow-gpu-with-pyinstaller), [Windows 10 pyinstaller tensorflow missing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732801/windows-10-pyinstaller-tensorflow-missing-modules/50580345), https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3754) discussing a similar problem, but the solutions suggested are not working in my case.

At first I was getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>   File "imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "hands_up_bending_counter_object_oriented.py", line 12, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "tf_pose__init__.py", line 5, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "tf_pose\runner.py", line 7, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "tf_pose\common.py", line 3, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>     File "imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.
>   [32124] Failed to execute script hands_up_bending_counter_object_oriented

I have tried to place the file _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd into a subdirectory `/tensorflow/python` in the dist folder (by modifying the `.spec` file), as suggested by (https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3754), but now the error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
>     File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>     File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "postural_analysis_fast.py", line 11, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>     File "c:\dev\anaconda\envs\terminal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
>     File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
>     File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>     File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.
>   [47340] Failed to execute script postural_analysis_fast​

Edit (24.04.2019):

I have tried to use Dependencies tool to analyze _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd, and here is the result: [Dependencies result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tfU0.png).

I cannot find in the [documentation of Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) what does the red question mark mean (maybe missing dll?), but all those dlls are already present in my *dist* folder (inside the main folder).

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem and applied the dependencies tool to _pywrap_tensorflow_internal (tensorflow-gpu 1.12). It requires some C:\WINDOWS\system32 files, and one of them is nvcuda.dll. This cuda file tends to be missing in other computers. Hope this helps.

[Dependencies results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTiPS.png)

1) https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/-BluoQjTSLM

2) https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your help, it certainly helped me understand the problem a little more, however where have you placed nvcuda.dll in order fix your problem? In my case this dll is located inside **/torch/lib** folder, together with *cudnn64_7.dll*, while most of the other dlls are located in the main folder, together with the .exe file.