# Python PyInstaller 4.0 packaging TensorFlow 2.0 project not working ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pyinstaller

I am trying to bundle a python application using pyinstaller that uses tensorflow.

I am now using Pyinstaller-4.0.dev0+2f4426f52, Tensorflow 2.0, Keras 2.3 and Python 3.7.3 all in a virtual environment.

I have tried various older versions, but each older version had a different issue that I could not resolve. I have dedicated 3 days to trying to solve this problem.

A simplified example of the script I am running is:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential()
```

I used the following command to run pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --log-level=DEBUG ^
    --onedir ^
    --clean ^
    --name MyModel ^
    --hidden-import=tensorflow_core ^
    --noupx ^
    main.py
```

Using hidden-import appears to be redundant, as the output states:

> DEBUG: Hidden import 'tensorflow_core' already found

There were no build errors or warnings in the log.

I have looked into the pyz-00.pyz file and can confirm that TensorFlow modules are included in the file. I confirmed that the archive contains:

> 'tensorflow_core.python': (1, 9871434, 2355),

However when I try to run the exe I get the following error:

> File "site-packages\tensorflow_core\python_init_.py", line 49, in
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'pywrap_tensorflow' from
>   'tensorflow_core.python'
>   (\dist\MyModel\tensorflow_core\python_init_.pyc)

It appears that pyinstaller can't deal with tensorflow, and I wondered whether anyone with experience here might know how to write a hook for it or knows of some other workaround?

Comment: You may try to add another `hidden-import=tensorflow_core.pywrap` but it may become a dead end as well. If you want some kind of neural network you could train neural network with Python and use compiled C++ code to use the trained network.

Comment: Hi @SzymonMaszke, thanks for the comment, I tried that and I got: ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow_core.pywrap' not found on build, and the same error as before on running the exe. I need to re-train the model every day with new data, so unfortunately I am stuck with Python right now.

Comment: Note similar thread on git here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4400

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the directory from which you are invoking this program? Sometimes errors like that come up when the current directory has a tensorflow subdirectory with an **init**.py in it, which Python will prefer to any other installations. You can also refer to below link for some more troubleshooting steps:

[Tensorflow-gpu with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620638/tensorflow-gpu-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: Hi, so the directory I run pyinstaller in is the base directory, which contains all my python code. Above that, is the env folder with my virtual environment in it, then within Lib\site-packages are the default tensorflow, tensorflow_core, tensorflow_estimator directories. There are no other directories called tensorflow anywhere in my folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages`
Copy the `tensorflow_core` folder, paste it to your Project Directory and rename it as:

```
tensorflow from tensorflow import keras
```

After `import tensorflow as tf`, it works for me. Please, check.